# D3, Second focus does not move when context changes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I follow this D3 example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667367 . In the example, there is a focus and a context. When the context changes, the focus will show the data in the context. My goal is to add another focus (focus2). To make it easier, the function of focus2 (at the moment) is the same as focus (the original focus). The expected result is that: when the brush moves, two focus (focus and focus2 in the code) will change. Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<!--head> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" type= "text/css" href="angle_view.css">
</head-->

<style>

svg {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.area {
  fill: steelblue;
  clip-path: url(#clip);
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.brush .extent {
  stroke: #fff;
  fill-opacity: .125;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
</style>

<body>
 <!--script type = "text/javascript" src = "../d3/d3.min.js"> </script-->
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.7/d3.min.js"></script>
 
 <p>Select a dataset from the list.</p>
 <select id = "datasetSelect" onchange = "datasetSelectFunction()">
   <option value="load_small_data_set">small dataset</option>
   <option value="load_whole_data_set">whole dataset</option>   
 </select>
 
 <!--script type = "text/javascript" src = "angle_view.js"> </script -->
 
 <script> 
 
 // main script
 var g_fn = null;
 var g_pan = null;
 var g_feature = null;
 var g_fn_pan = null;
 
// init_angle_feature_view();
 var margin  = {top: 10,  right: 30,  bottom: 370, left: 40};
 var margin2 = {top: 250, right: 30, bottom: 130, left: 40};
 var margin3 = {top: 500, right: 30, bottom: 20, left: 40};
 var width   = 960 - margin.left - margin.right;
 var height  = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
 var height2 = 600 - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;
 var height3 = 600 - margin3.top - margin3.bottom;


 // set scales
 var x  = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]);
 var x2 = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]);
 var x3 = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]);
 var y  = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
 var y2 = d3.scale.linear().range([height2, 0]);
 var y3 = d3.scale.linear().range([height3, 0]);

 var xAxis  = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom");
 var xAxis2 = d3.svg.axis().scale(x2).orient("bottom");
 var xAxis3 = d3.svg.axis().scale(x3).orient("bottom");
 var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left");

 var brush = d3.svg.brush()
     .x(x3)     // x scale
     .on("brush", brushed);

 var area = d3.svg.area()  // area on the top, detailed view of pan angle
     .interpolate("monotone")
     .x(function(d) { return x(d.frame_number); })
     .y0(height)
     .y1(function(d) { return y(d.pan); });
 
 var area2 = d3.svg.area()  // area in the middle, detailed view of feature
  .interpolate("monotone")
  .x(function(d){return x2(d.frame_number);})
  .y0(height2)
  .y1(function(d){return y2(d.pan); });

 var area3 = d3.svg.area() // area on the bottom, global view of pan angle
     .interpolate("monotone")
     .x(function(d) { return x3(d.frame_number); })
     .y0(height3)
     .y1(function(d) { return y3(d.pan); });

 var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
     .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
     .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);

 svg.append("defs").append("clipPath")  // what is defs?, defs is not directly rendered. what is clipPath? draw only inside width x height
     .attr("id", "clip")  // what is clip and id do
     .append("rect")
     .attr("width", width)
     .attr("height", height);

 var focus = svg.append("g")
     .attr("class", "focus")   // where does focus come from?
     .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
 
 var focus2 = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "focus")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin2.left + "," + margin2.top + ")");

 var context = svg.append("g")
     .attr("class", "context")
     .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin3.left + "," + margin3.top + ")"); 
 
 function datasetSelectFunction(){
  var x = document.getElementById("datasetSelect").value; 
  //console.log(x);
  
  if (x == "load_small_data_set")
  {
   // load frame number, pan data   
   d3.csv("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/54750216/javascript/sampled_fn_pan_small.csv", function(error, data) {
    if (error) throw error;
    // sparse data    
     data.forEach(function(d){
     d.frame_number  = parseInt(d.frame_number);
     d.pan = parseFloat(d.pan);      
     });
    g_fn_pan = data;
     
     d3.csv("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/54750216/javascript/sampled_fn_dim_feature_small.csv", function(error, feature) {
       if (error) throw error;
       // Coerce the CSV data to the appropriate types.    
       feature.forEach(function(d) {
         d.fn      = parseInt(d.frame_number);
         d.dim     = parseInt(d.dim);
         d.feature =  parseFloat(d.feature);
       });  
       g_feature = feature;
     
     angle_feature_view(g_fn_pan, g_feature);     
      });    
     
     });
   console.log("load_small_data_set");    
   // load frame number, feature data         
        
  }
  else if (x == "load_whole_data_set")
  {
   // load frame number, pan data   
   d3.csv("sampled_data/sampled_fn_pan.csv", function(error, data) {
    if (error) throw error;
    // sparse data    
     data.forEach(function(d){
     d.frame_number  = parseInt(d.frame_number);
     d.pan = parseFloat(d.pan);      
     });
    g_fn_pan = data;
     
     d3.csv("sampled_data/sampled_fn_dim_feature.csv", function(error, feature) {
       if (error) throw error;
       // Coerce the CSV data to the appropriate types.    
       feature.forEach(function(d) {
         d.fn      = parseInt(d.frame_number);
         d.dim     = parseInt(d.dim);
         d.feature =  parseFloat(d.feature);
       });  
       g_feature = feature;
     
   //  angle_feature_view(g_fn_pan, g_feature);     
      });    
     
     });
   console.log("load_whole_data_set");
  }  
 }
 
 // visualize frame number, pan angle and feature 
 function angle_feature_view(fn_pan, feature)
 {
  var fn_min  = d3.min(fn_pan, function(d){return d.frame_number});
     var fn_max  = d3.max(fn_pan, function(d){return d.frame_number});
  var pan_min = d3.min(fn_pan, function(d){return d.pan});
  var pan_max = d3.max(fn_pan, function(d){return d.pan});
  
    x.domain([fn_min, fn_max]);  
    y.domain([pan_min, pan_max]);     
      
  x2.domain(x.domain());
  y2.domain(y.domain());
    // bottom
    x3.domain(x.domain());
    y3.domain(y.domain());  

  // draw fn pan detail view
  
    focus.append("path")
         .datum(fn_pan)
         .attr("class", "area")
         .attr("d", area);

    focus.append("g")
       .attr("class", "x axis")
       .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
       .call(xAxis);

    focus.append("g")
       .attr("class", "y axis")
       .call(yAxis);  
  
  // add focus2 in this place
    focus2.append("path")
         .datum(fn_pan)
         .attr("class", "area")
         .attr("d", area2);

       focus2.append("g")
         .attr("class", "x axis")
         .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
         .call(xAxis2);

    focus2.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);  

  // brush?
    context.append("path")
        .datum(fn_pan)
        .attr("class", "area")
        .attr("d", area3);

    context.append("g")
       .attr("class", "x axis")
       .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height3 + ")")
       .call(xAxis3);

    context.append("g")
       .attr("class", "x brush")
       .call(brush)
       .selectAll("rect")
       .attr("y", -6)
       .attr("height", height3 + 7);   
 }
 
 function brushed() {
   x.domain(brush.empty() ? x3.domain() : brush.extent());
   focus.select(".area").attr("d", area);
   focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
   focus2.select(".area").attr("d", area2);  // I add focus2 in this place
   focus2.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis2);
   console.log("call brushed");
 } 
 
 
 </script>
 
 
</body>
```

Please pay attention to focus, focus2 and context related area.
The problem is that the focus2 view does not change when the context changes. It always show the whole dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it, you only forgot to update the domain of the second scale.

Adding `x2.domain(brush.empty() ? x3.domain() : brush.extent());` into the `brushed()` function solves it.

Comment: Please add some explanation. Your answer might get flagged "low quality" and might eventually be removed without.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I added a line to explain the solution but it's really simple, there isn't that much to add really...

Comment: @JohannesJander , hope you don't mind me asking. I believe I answered this question (although a rather simple one) correctly. What does it take to get the answer accepted? I'm trying to earn some reputations points here. Is it completely up to the person asking the question? What if he's not interested anymore? sorry for being offtopic

Comment: Yes, @KarolPal, it's totally up to the person who had asked the question. I know it sucks, it happens a lot.  Still, keep up answering questions and over time, you'll receive reputation. Just don't let the gamification of Stackoverflow pull you in so tightly that you answer questions just to gain rep. That way is burnout.